# Is kdump not installed when /etc/kdump.conf is missing?

Tags: centos, server-crashes, dump, kdump

I have CentOS 5.8 system. And I want to set up the kdump.
I was following this [configuration steps on kdump](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-kdump-configuration-cli.html).
However I was not able to locate /etc/kdump.conf.
I tried using the find and locate command to find kdump.conf, but it return no result.
Does it mean that kdump is not installed or supported on my system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kdump is supported on CentOS 5.8 but the instructions that you followed assume that you have the `kexec-tools` package installed. Install `kexec-tools` and then follow the instructions.

Answer (score 2):

> However I was not able to locate /etc/kdump.conf

Because you haven't installed the `kexec-tools` package:

```
# yum provides /etc/kdump.conf 
Loaded plugins: etckeeper, fastestmirror, verify
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.vietoss.com
 * atomic: www5.atomicorp.com
 * base: mirror.vietoss.com
 * epel: mirrors.ustc.edu.cn
 * extras: mirror.vietoss.com
 * jpackage-generic: sunsite.rediris.es
 * jpackage-generic-updates: sunsite.rediris.es
 * rpmforge: mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net
 * updates: mirror.vietoss.com
kexec-tools-1.102pre-161.el5.x86_64 : The kexec/kdump userspace component.
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/kdump.conf
```